# Class.getAnnotations() / getDeclaredAnnotations() returns empty array for subclass

Tags: java, inheritance, interface, annotations

I have an annotation defined like:

```
@Inherited
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
@interface Retriable {

}
```

And I'm using it like this:

```
@Retriable
interface MyInterface {
    public void myMethod();
}
```

Now, I have a second interface, which extends the first:

```
interface MySecondInterface extends MyInterface {

}
```

I want to get ***all*** annotations for `MySecondInterface`, it means that I would like to also get the annotation(s) defined on super interfaces.

What I tried:

Class clazz = MySecondInterface.class;

```
Retriable annotation = clazz.getAnnotation(Retriable.class);
System.out.println("Retriable annotation: " + annotation);

Annotation[] annotations = clazz.getAnnotations();
System.out.println("Annotations: " + Arrays.toString(annotations));

annotations = clazz.getDeclaredAnnotations();
System.out.println("Declared Annotations: " + Arrays.toString(annotations));
```

The result is:

```
Retriable annotation: null
Annotations: []
Declared Annotations: []
```

In all cases it can't find the `Retriable` annotation inherited from `MyInterface`. ([DEMO](http://ideone.com/X8rJGG))

Is there a way to make it recognize annotations of super-interface?

Comment: No. Annotations aren't inherited from interfaces only super classes, this is according to the spec.

Comment: @M.Deinum Hm, I see. I have this scenario: `MyInterface` is an interface that contains definitions for an EJB. Then I have `MyInterfaceLocal` and `MyInterfaceRemote` which extend `MyInterface`. When someone does the lookup for `MyInterfaceRemote` I need to process annotations, which are defined on the class that contains method definitions(`MyInterface`). Is there any way I could read these annotations? What would you suggest?

Comment: You would need to figure out if the interface is implemented and then parse the interfaces.

Answer (score 0):

From the javadocs of `java.lang.annotation.Inherited`:

```
    Note that this meta-annotation type has no effect if the annotated type is used to annotate 
    anything other than a class. Note also that this meta-annotation only causes annotations to be 
    inherited from superclasses; annotations on implemented interfaces have no effect.
```

so change interface to class. it will affect

```
@Retriable
class MyClass {
    public void myMethod(){

    }
}

class MySecondClass extends MyClass {

}
```

Comment: I see. BTW, I can't follow the example. I need interfaces as I'm working with EJBs. I need to find another solution. Thank you!